# How to add GrantRead parameter in s3 UploadInput?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, file-upload, amazon-s3

I've checked UploadInput type in the [package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3manager/#UploadInput)

It has this part

```
    // Gives the grantee READ, READ_ACP, and WRITE_ACP permissions on the object.
GrantFullControl *string `location:"header" locationName:"x-amz-grant-full-control" type:"string"`

// Allows grantee to read the object data and its metadata.
GrantRead *string `location:"header" locationName:"x-amz-grant-read" type:"string"`

// Allows grantee to read the object ACL.
GrantReadACP *string `location:"header" locationName:"x-amz-grant-read-acp" type:"string"`

// Allows grantee to write the ACL for the applicable object.
GrantWriteACP *string `location:"header" locationName:"x-amz-grant-write-acp" type:"string"`
```

How do I use GrantRead in my following request?

```
 result, err := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(Conf.AWS_S3_BUCKET),
        Key:    &filename,
        Body:   f,
    })
```

I'm trying to make my files public to READ

Comment: It should be none of those things, but rather `ACL: "public-read"` inside the `UploadInput`. Give that a try?

Comment: Yes I was wrong. I fixed it the other way, on the server side. Thank you :)